# jQuery UI .position() misses height of target element set with jQuery .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**Hello experts**

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="full-height">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
</div>
```

I'm setting the height of `div.full-height` with jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setHeight() {
        viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.full-height').height(viewportHeight);
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
});
```

Now I try to set the position of the `h1` in `div.full-height` to `center center` with jQuery UI as follows:

```
$('.full-height > h1').position({
    my: 'center center',
    at: 'center center',
    of: '.full-height'
});
```

The problem is, that it's only positioned correctly if I set a fixed `height` property in CSS.

Otherwise `div.full-height` has full height, but the `h2` inside it sticks at the top because jQuery UI's `.position()` function doesn't know that `div.full-height` has 100% height.

How can I get it working?

Greetings

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi experts**

That ws quick. :-)

I just solved the problem by inluding the jQuery UI function inside if the resizing funktion as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setHeight() {
        viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.full-height').height(viewportHeight);
        $('.full-height > h1').position({
            my: 'center center',
            at: 'center center',
            of: '.full-height'
        });
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Greetings

Ralph